# How can I get a reference to the object changed in a PropertyValueChanged event?

Tags: .net, propertygrid

I can add a handler for the `PropertyValueChanged` event on my `PropertyGrid`. If the user changes properties of the `SelectedObject`, this works fine. However if the `SelectedObject` has properties which are themselves objects, the user can also edit properties of that object. I still get the `PropertyValueChanged` event raised which is good, but I can't find a way of getting a reference to the object that they have changed.

Viewing the ChangedItem property of the `PropertyValueChangedEventArgs` parameter in the Watch window, I can see that there is an `Instance` property in `PropertyDescriptorGridEntry` but I don't seem to be able to access this from my code.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do the job:

```
e.ChangedItem.GetType().GetProperty("Instance").GetValue(e.ChangedItem)
```

Answer (score 1):

When the `PropertyValueChanged` event is raised, it has an associated `PropertyValueChangedEventArgs`. This object has a `ChangedItem` member that holds the `GridItem` that was changed. So if you want to do something with the changed item, your handler could look like:

```
private void OnPropertyValueChanged(Object sender, PropertyValueChangedEventArgs args) {
    Console.WriteLine($"The changed item was {args.ChangedItem}");
}
```

Comment: I know that, but ChangedItem does not provide a reference to the object that was changed.

Answer (score 0):

you could try:

```
var obj = (sender as propertyGrid1).SelectedObject;
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**